# Compiler Intrisics: Specify Register?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, intrinsics

Is there some way to specify the registers with compiler intrinsics?

For example, `_mm_load_si128` is said to encode the instruction `movdqa xmm, m128`, but I cannot see a way to specify actually which register you want to be used.

I cannot use inline assembly either since VS does not support it for 64-bit so I'd have to write the shellcode for each function myself then allocate memory for the function at run-time, which seems like a bad option.

The reason for this is that I want to fill each one of the XMM registers with data then unload it at specific addresses in memory.

Comment: You *could* use GNU C register-asm variables (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html), but there's no need to do that.  Let the compiler decide to use all 16 registers, or write a whole function in a stand-alone `.asm` file.  (No need for shellcode!  Separate .asm files are the normal way to link asm with C without inline asm.)  Or use a better compiler that supports inline asm for targets other than 32-bit x86 (e.g. clang or GCC).

Comment: You can write your assembly code in asm files, add these to your project, build them with NASM (from your project) and call asm functions from C code. This way is used in drivers, for example https://github.com/intel/haxm.

Comment: Can you show an [mcve] of the code you have that's not (reliably?) compiling the way you want?  Like doing some of the stores before all the loads?  Maybe a compiler memory barrier could work to force the compiler to order the loads vs. stores the way you want.

Comment: Re “The reason for this is that I want to fill each one of the XMM registers with data then unload it at specific addresses in memory”: That is not a reason to use a specific register. Data can be written to selected memory addresses with no need to use any particular register for that.

Comment: re: my first comment: forgot to say that `register __m128i v0 asm("xmm0") = _mm_load_si128(...)` is only officially supported by GCC as a way to make it pick xmm0 for an `asm` statement like `asm("..." :"+x"(v0));`, but in practice GCC will still use XMM0 inside the function body, at least between function calls or something like that.  Clang won't, only respecting register-asm for actual `asm` statements.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have specified that I use VS in the OP so sadly I can't make use of any GCC extensions. Regardless, I have tried following nevilad's suggestion but VS has a serious issue with its support with NASM and it frequently cant find the functions despite making the public and editing the name 100 times so I have settled for just creating them all at run-time and locking the created pages into memory in order to use the functions

Comment: how i understand msvc has `ml` (MASM really) . So you can create `.obj` with it.

Comment: but forget about projects. use `nmake` .  https://github.com/alexeyneu/tool3/blob/release/tool3/makefile   This one is for mfc

Answer (score 0):

of course you can. make `.o` with nasm or use `ml` from msvc (but i didn't use the latter) . then you can link it to elf/exe . Ofc you can specify this stuff only in assembler